# Close vote reason display issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

I've just (yesterday or today) started seeing poor text positioning on the close vote dialog, specifically that the already-selected reason's description is overlapping with the title:

[image: off topic because]

[image: primarily opinion based]

This is on:

```
 Version:       48.0.2685.32 (PGO) - Opera is up to date  
 Update stream: Stable  
 System:        Windows 10 64-bit
```

Comment: Same here - Win10 (32-bit) running Chrome browser version 61.0.3163.100.

Comment: I do remember seeing something similar the other day using Chrome Windows 8 but I cannot get it to replicate now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The related questions on [Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301503/misaligned-options-still-in-the-close-vote-popup-dialog) and [SO Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357243/text-overlap-in-vote-to-close-dialog) already have a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag.

It does appear that completion does not include actually *deploying* the fix, though.